# How can I save a function defintion

Tags: functions, defun, symbol-function

I want to extend a standard Emacs function (`package--save-selected-packages`), but to cover my tracks I want to save the old defintion under a new name and then redintion teh standard function.

I tried `fset` but that creates rather something like an *alias* from a new name to the old name, but it does not save the old definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `symbol-function` to obtain the current function slot value for a given symbol, which is typically what you'd be after here.

You can store that value anywhere you want, and restore it later (perhaps with `fset`).

> I tried `fset` but that creates rather something like an *alias* from a new name to the old name, but it does not save the old definition...

If you did something like `(fset 'foo 'bar)` then you are only storing the *name* of the function, rather than the function value associated with the name.  Function indirection would therefore return whatever the *current* value associated with that name happens to be.

Comment: What a great explanation! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!